# Question on modular arithmetic and primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Given a prime $p$ of the form $p = 4k + 1$, with $k$ being an integer, I am trying to prove that $n^{({p-1})/{2}}$ leaves $1$ or $-1$ as remainder when divided by $p$, for any $n \in \{2, \ldots, p-1\}$. Approximately, how many such $n$ are possible for which it leaves $-1$ as remainder?

Comment: To give an answer that would be useful to you we need to know a bit more about your background. Also, you could try and dispel the thought that this is an attempt to out source homework. Read [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619) for various ways of doing that.

Comment: And as a concrete hint for getting started on problems like this: What happens when $p=5$ or $p=13$? Please report what you found when you tested small cases like these!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Lil' Fermat asserts that for all such $n$s, $n^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ – inther words, they're all roots of the polynomial
$$x^{p-1}=\Bigl(x^{\tfrac{p-1}2}-1\Bigr)=\Bigl(x^{\tfrac{p-1}2}+1\Bigr)$$
Now you can use that a polynomial of degree $d$ over a field cannot have more than $d$ roots in this field to conclude.